# Bounty as extra points to the answered

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I would like to recognize a good answer giving away some points to the guy who answered. In this case I did a dumb and incorrect question and the guy foreseen why my question was incorrect and corrected it (curious guys [can see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707499/rspec-match-array-for-empty-array-fails?answertab=active#tab-top)), but I already did this before some times. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that this is a somewhat common practice.

The thing is that waiting for the bounty time and then one extra day to reward the answer takes... time. I know that the bounty time is to avoid giving bounty hastily, but many times the answer for a well-defined question is correct or wrong, no middle way.

Plus, when using bounty hunter the way I'm doing, I don't want my question to have any extra attention. I just want to reward a guy.

What about open the possibility to give away some extra bounty instantly for the accepted answer? Or even better, add a "reward" option, since it is semantically different from a bounty?

Note that it has it value to SO too - I'm actually telling, judging by that answer, that this guy is `X * 2` points more reliable then myself.

Comment: No, because that allows for (more) bounty abuse.

Comment: @MartijnPieters where can I read about bounty abuse, to understand the problem better?

Comment: @MartijnPieters if the problem is `are there to prevent abuse, for example continuously transferring some of your rep to a buddy of yours.`, don't the max bounty per day limitation deals with it?

Comment: No, there is no central article to read about bounty abuse; we don't like to advertise all the ways people try to game the system, generally speaking.

Comment: @fotanus No, the max bounty per day *doesn't* deal with it.